# Excel VBA - For Loop taking far too long to execute

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script which I have designed in order to hide rows that do not contain data, the script looks through column A starting from Row 7. If it finds rows that do not contain values, it will hide those rows from sight.  Unfortunately this script takes over 1 minute to run on large sheets in its present form.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to re-write this script in order to make it faster?  It needs to run in 5 seconds max

```
Sub hideAllRows()
Dim Checklist As Variant

    UnlockSheet

    Call Show_Hide("Row", "7:519", True)
    Call Show_Hide("Row", "529:1268", True)

    Checklist = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
     For I = UBound(Checklist, 1) To LBound(Checklist, 1) Step -1
       If Checklist(I, 1) <> "" Then
          Rows(I & ":" & I).Select
          Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       End If
     Next I
```

Comment: Do you have constants (e.g. typed values), formulas or a combination of both in column A?

Comment: they are primarily formulas, to pick up if Column E has a value or not, if so it populates Column A with information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code in order to make things simpler.
One of the issues is that your code is firing events "like crazy" (each time you do a Select, an event is fired).

A. If you want to use your code as is, I suggest you add at the beginning

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and add in the last line:

```
Application.EnableEvents = true
```

B. I suggest that you do the hiding "in one blow", after the loop has ended. Here is how:

```
Dim Checklist As Variant
dim sRowsToHide as string

UnlockSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call Show_Hide("Row", "7:519", True)
Call Show_Hide("Row", "529:1268", True)

Checklist = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
 For I = UBound(Checklist, 1) To LBound(Checklist, 1) Step -1
   If Checklist(I, 1) <> "" Then
if sRowsToHide = "" then
   sRowsToHide = I & ":" & I
else
   sRowsToHide = sRowsToHide  & "," & I & ":" & I 
end if
   End If
 Next I

 ActiveSheet.Range(sRowsToHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

You can use the following line to see how such a thing would work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("2:2,14:14,17:17,19:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ScreenUpdating, it will only update the sheet once the loop is done instead of updating every time

```
Dim Checklist As Variant

    UnlockSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call Show_Hide("Row", "7:519", True)
    Call Show_Hide("Row", "529:1268", True)

    Checklist = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
     For I = UBound(Checklist, 1) To LBound(Checklist, 1) Step -1
       If Checklist(I, 1) <> "" Then
          Rows(I & ":" & I).Select
          Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       End If
     Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will hide all rows that have constants (e.g. *typed values*) in column A.

```
Sub hide_A_values()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This next one will hide all rows that have formulas in column A.

```
Sub hide_A_values()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, this will hide all rows that have constants (e.g. *typed values*) or formulas in column A.

```
Sub hide_A_values()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that you have to provide error control or risk dealing with the dreaded `Runtime error: 1004 No cells were found` if there are no constants or formulas to hide. `On Error Resume Next` typically takes care of this.

```
Sub hide_A_values()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The only case not covered by those is formulas returning empty strings (e.g. "") which are not considered truly blank.